# Positioning issue on different pages

Tags: html, css

Basically I have a web page which contains a slider, a banner, a menu and content.

My HTML code  looks like:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    ...
</div>
<div class="banner">
    ...
</div>
<div class="navigation">
    ...
</div>
<div class="content">
    ...
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.banner
{
    z-index: 1000;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 140px;
}

.navigation
{
    margin: 0px auto 0;
}

.content
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Slider is displayed only on homepage and everything is OK. But if I open a content page `div.slider` is not displayed (which I do want this) and `div.navigation`  goes up to page's top and looks under the `div.banner` since `div.banner` has `z-index` and `position:absolute` (see Actual view 1).

I have tried to add `margin-bottom:140px` to `div.banner` but did not work. Then I tried to put `margin-top:140px` to `div.navigation` but there is a gap between `div.slider` and `div.navigation` in homepage (see Actual view 2).

I want `div.slider` and `div.banner` to stick to page's top together but `div.slider` will be under `div.banner`. Also when `div.slider` is not displayed I want `div.navigation` to be displayed right after `div.banner` (see Desired view).

You may also want to check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fn5yj/2/)
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "if I open another page" ?

Comment: @CléementMalet another content page on same web site

Comment: And there is no other PHP or JS code around ? Is the relative path to your CSS still the same ? There is no reason for `slideshow` to disappear from a page to another if the structure of the HTML remains the same.

Comment: why have you used `position:absolute` in first place??

Comment: @NoobEditor I have used `position:absolute` in order to show slider underneath of banner

Comment: If the HTML markup changes from Homepage to other pages cannot put a class on navigation in order to add the desired margin-top?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is incorrect :

What is **expected to be repeated on other pages**, keep it `relative`....DOM which is **visible only on 1 page**, keep it `absolute`, this way you'll avoid any headaches as `relative` is a kind of *by-default* position!

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <!--
    keep it :
      position:absolute;
      top : 0;
      left : 0;
      right : 0;
    -->
</div>
<div class="banner">
    <!--
     position : relative
     place top left right according to your DOM layout
    -->
</div>
```

Comment: @zkanoca : *something* ??

Comment: menu and content stay underneath slider.

Comment: @zkanoca : sorry for late reply...i am active during office hours!! :)
you have problem with your DOM layout, `banner`should come before `slideshow`, if slideshow's `height` is fixed, then a simple layout is this => http://jsfiddle.net/Fn5yj/3/ (*keep in mind the solution is not responsive*)